# python2.7 quit within two input in the same line (separated by space)

Tags: python-2.7, input, split, valueerror

I have to input two value in the same line, and they are separated by space.
so that the output would be some thing like this

> 123 456
>
> input is 123 and 456

so I use the code

```
a ,b = map(float, raw_input().split())
print ('input is '), a ,(' and '), b
```

This work
But I want to quit the script immediately when user input "-1"
for example, if user input -1 for value for a, program will stop reading input from user, print 'wrong input'

> wrong input

But when i try to input '-1' and press 'enter'

is said

> ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

is that mean I should not use 'map(float, raw_input().split())' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your parameters into a list and then process them:

```
params = map(float, raw_input().split())
```

you can then check if params[0] is -1 or the length of the array is different than expected. After your checks you can assign:

```
a,b=params
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enter just one input (-1), while trying to store it in a,b, pytjon throws a traceback.

Instead of storing in a,b , just store it in a list.

Use the following if you want to use map function :

1. Case of valid input :

   ```
   >>> a = map(float, raw_input().split())
   123 456
   >>> if a[0] == -1 :
   ...     print 'Wrong Input'
   ... else :
   ...     print 'input is',a[0],' '.join(['and '+str(i) for i in a[1:]])
   ...
   input is 123.0 and 456.0
   ```
2. Case of invalid input-

   ```
   >>> a = map(float, raw_input().split())
   -1
   >>> if a[0] == -1 :
   ...     print 'Wrong Input'
   ... else :
   ...     print 'input is',a[0],' '.join(['and '+str(i) for i in a[1:]])
   ...
   Wrong Input
   ```
3. Something extra (valid)-

   ```
   >>> a = map(float, raw_input().split())
   12 34 56 78
   >>> if a[0] == -1 :
   ...     print 'Wrong Input'
   ... else :
   ...     print 'input is',a[0],' '.join(['and '+str(i) for i in a[1:]])
   ...
   input is 12.0 and 34.0 and 56.0 and 78.0
   ```
4. Something extra (invalid)-

   ```
   >>> a = map(float, raw_input().split())
   -1 234
   >>> if a[0] == -1 :
   ...     print 'Wrong Input'
   ... else :
   ...     print 'input is',a[0],' '.join(['and '+str(i) for i in a[1:]])
   ...
   Wrong Input
   ```